# How to detect back button click and make webview go back

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to build a webview app for one of my projects using Xamarin but I can't seem to figure out how to make the webview element go to previous page instead of closing the app.

So I have figured out how to detect the back button being pressed and prevent it from closing the app but I want to make the web page go back and if the web page can't go back then close the app.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms; 
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml; 
using Application = Xamarin.Forms.Application; 

namespace myNewApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public class WebPage : ContentPage
    {
        public object _browser { get; private set; }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {

                base.OnBackButtonPressed();
                return true;

        }

        public WebPage()
        {


            var browser = new Xamarin.Forms.WebView();

            browser.Source = "https://myurl.com";


            Content = browser;

        }



    }
}
```

I have tried a couple of answers and I found this bit of code but it doesn't work as the override can't access the public WebPage browser var:

```
if (browser.CanGoBack)
            {
                browser.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnBackButtonPressed();
                return true;
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to make `browser` a class level variable so you can access it anywhere in your page.

```
public class WebPage : ContentPage
{
    Xamarin.Forms.Webview browser;

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {

        base.OnBackButtonPressed();

        if (browser.CanGoBack)
        {
            browser.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();
            return true;
        }

    }

    public WebPage()
    {


        browser = new Xamarin.Forms.WebView();

        browser.Source = "https://myurl.com";


        Content = browser;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I knew I was missing something removing var and setting Xamarin.Forms.Webview browser; did the trick

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't the default behaviour? Why does the back-button close the app by default?